# enabled load test from vsts build using Apache Jmeter load test, but from run duration i see few values only

Tags: jmeter, azure-pipelines

Enabled load test from vsts build using Apache Jmeter load test, but from run duration I see few values, upto 5mins, I am able to run the test, but I want to run my test for 15 minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's by design.

The maximum limitation is up to 300 seconds (5mins) for task: [Test: Cloud-based Apache JMeter Load Test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/tasks/test/run-jmeter-load-test?view=vsts). We cannot change the limitation.

However you can try another way : Go to the **Load Test** hub and [Run Apache JMeter load tests with VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=vsts):

But please note that for Azure load testing there is a limitation of maximum test duration and number of concurrent users based on the **License type** : See [Azure load testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/test/load-test/reference-qa?view=vsts#azure-load-testing)

---

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately we cannot change the limitation of the task: `Test: Cloud-based Apache JMeter Load Test`.

I have submitted a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34934782-add-more-run-duration-options-for-cloud-based) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dzimiks for your answer, yes i can run the test from Load test , i tried this and working fine ,but we are looking for CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: @seenu Unfortunately we cannot change the limitation of the task: `Test: Cloud-based Apache JMeter Load Test`. I have submitted a [user voice here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/34934782-add-more-run-duration-options-for-cloud-based) to suggest the feature, you can go and vote it up to achieve that in future.